# undefined method `mount_uploader'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

i just followed the instructions
of ''carrierwave''[https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave]

Added `gem 'carrierwave', '~> 2.0'` in to my Gemfile

Make `rails generate uploader Image`, them make `rails g migration add_image_to_courses` and `rails db:migrate`
This is my controller

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
def new
@course = Course.new
end

private
  def course_params
      params.require(:course).permit(:description, :ages, :price, :name, :image)
    end
end
```

and this is my html

```
<%= form_with model: @course, html: {multipart: true } do |form| %>


 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Image</label>
      <%= form.file_field :image %>
    </div>
    <%= form.submit "Submit",  :class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" %><br>
  </form>

  <% end %>
```

Comment: You don't mount an uploader in a controller it would be mounted in the model. [From the Docs](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#activerecord): *"Open your **model** file and mount the uploader:"*

Comment: thank you, after the fix everything worked